# Streamlit - How to show .tif images (possibly large size) in Streamlit using st.image?

Tags: tiff, streamlit

I am trying to visualize high resolution *.tif images using streamlit. I tried using both a url to the image and the downloaded image. All I get is a "0" similar to a `st.write("0")`.

What I tried to do:

```
import streamlit as st

st.image("http://www.bmsc.washington.edu/raster3d/examples/density.tiff")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pillow library.

```
import streamlit as st 
from PIL import Image


fn = 'f:/downloads/density.tiff'
image = Image.open(fn)
st.image(image)
```

#### Output

[image]